# Why isnt cypress able to get my auth token from local storage?

Tags: local-storage, cypress

```js
const token = window.localStorage.getItem("token");
cy.request({
  method: "POST",
  url: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  headers: {
    Authorization: token,
  },
  body: {
    
  },
})
```

If I log "token" it is null

The correct token is saved in the Local storage with the key "token"

P.S. There is no "second layer in my localstorage so accessing it with NameOfLocalStorage.token" wont fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Because cypress tests and your app are not in the same frame. To access frame related to your application you can do the following :

```
cy.window().then((win) => {
   const token = win.localStorage.getItem("token");
})
```

Comment: Actually, that doesn't apply to `localStorage`. I thought so too, but I tried it out and found setting `window.localStorage.setItem("token", "abc")` gave the same value back in the above code.